# How to merge two Gatsby Starter libraries?

Tags: gatsby

I am interested in making a portfolio website and wanted to merhe two starter libraries. But I am not quite sure if it is possible or how to do that as I am quite nee to Gatsby and React. Would love some suggestions on building the website!

Answer (score 1):

Gatsby does not provide a way to merge two starters out of the box but you can modify any starter you want as per this [doc](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/modifying-a-starter/).

Hence instead of merging two starters what I would suggest is use the [gatsby default starter](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/starters/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default/) and add [gatsby theme](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/themes/using-a-gatsby-theme/) based on your need.

PS: Check out this [flowchart](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/plugins-themes-and-starters/#deciding-which-to-use) to understand in gatsby way!!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any built-in functionality to merge 2 repositories or starters in Gatsby. The only option to achieve what you want is to gather from each repository/starter the plugins, configurations, customizations that you want to take and install them in your new repository based on your needs. If none of them are using [shadowing](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/themes/shadowing/) the integration will become easier than if they use, since the customization will be restricted on the generated components not in the theme configuration itself.

Choose wisely:

[image]